# PostgreSql Search return array of dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a Text[] column which stores `BillDate` in `dd-mm-yyyy` format

```
Id  BillDate text[]
--------------------------------------
1   20-01-2018
2   10-01-2018, 12-01-2018
3   19-12-2017, 13-07-2017, 20-01-2018
4   25-12-2017, 18-12-2017
```

My PostgreSQL need to filter bill date from & to range i.e.:

`12-01-2018 to 21-01-2018` and the result should be ID: 1, 2, 3 because at-least one value exist in `BillDate` between range

My query:

```
var datefrom = ['12-01-2018'];
var dateto = ['21-01-2018'];

' SELECT "Id", "BillDate" FROM "Table" '+
' where "BillDate" between $1 and $2 ',[datefrom,dateto]
```

But I am not getting excepted results, as Postgres checks date in `yyyy-dd-mm` format

Comment: Why on earth are you storing dates as `text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, ask Postgres to understand your date format, to be able to cast it:

```
t=# set datestyle to DMY;
SET
```

now, get ids with at least one date from array in range:

```
t=# with w as (
  select id,unnest(bd)::date bd
  from w
)
select id
from w
where bd between '12-01-2018' and '21-01-2018'
;
 id
----
  1
  2
  3
(3 rows)
```

now, if you want id and billdate, join result against original table on `(id)`